# Escaping forward slash on expr

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to escape / on the code below but nothing works. I already tried / \/ [/]... and I always get 500 error response.

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /^.*xxx/xxx.*$/">
```

So how do I escape the forward slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think you will have to use the encoded version or use the alternative regex syntax.

perhaps using the encoded form of `/`.

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /^.*xxx\x2Fxxx.*$/">
```

Or using the alternate regex syntax for better legibility

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ m#^.*xxx/xxx.*$#">
```

Comment: do you mind providing me the link of apache where it explains the usage of "m#"? I cant find it nowhere.

Comment: thank you so much Panama, you are awesome! I searched this all around and couldnt find! :)